# How can I pass list of strongly type objects from controller to a dropdown on a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dropdown

I would like to pass list of strongly typed object to a dropdown which is located on my view.

Usually to achieve this I used ViewBags like in following example:

```
public ActionResult ChooseLevel()
{

     List<Levels> LevelList = GetAllLevels();

     ViewBag.LevelList = LevelList 

     var model = new Levels();
     return View(model);
}
```

And I would simply write this on a view, and I would get all my levels listed there:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LevelId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LevelId, new SelectList(ViewBag.LevelList, "LevelId", "LevelName"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I'm wondering can I simply pass my list of Levels there, and choose them from dropdown list, without storing them to a viewbag first?
For example :

```
public ActionResult ChooseLevel()
{
     List<Levels> LevelList = GetAllLevels();
     return View(LevelList);
}
```

On a view I would accept multiple items by writing `IEnumerable` on a view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Levels>
```

and after that I could somehow choose only one item and post it back to a server?

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: Just a clarification: Why using an `IEnumerable<Levels>` in the view if you expect only single item from `DropDownList` passed into viewmodel? Even you can pass the viewmodel list with `Model.LevelList` like `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LevelId, new SelectList(Model.LevelList, "LevelId", "LevelName"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })`.

Comment: Binding a dropdownlist to itself makes no sense (your model is `Level` and the options your generating are for `Level`. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need view with only one dropdown there (Level objects inside), and that dropdown should allow me to select one of the Levels

Comment: So therefore you should have a view model with 2 properties - `int SelectedLevel` (to bind the selected option value to) and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LevelsList` to generate the options

Comment: Refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a typical example of who your view model would look like

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this List to your existing Model or View Model:

```
class ModelName
{
public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> lstTypes { get; set; }
public virtual int intTypeId { get; set; }
//Other existing properties here
}
```

On your Controller, you can now add this list to your Model before you return to your view:

```
            ModelName objModel = new ModelName();
            List<Levels> LevelList = GetAllLevels();

            objModel.lstTypes = LevelList.Select(y => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = y.LevelId.ToString(),
                Text = y.LevelName.ToString()
            });
         return View(objModel);
```

Then you can now display it on your view:

```
@model ModelName
//First parameter will be the Id that will be selected by your user when they post it
//Second parameter will be the enumerable list of dropdown
//Third parameter is the default option which is optional, and the last is the HTML attributes
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.intTypeId, Model.lstTypes , "Please select an item", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create new viewmodel that contains multiple models (old model and LevelList model). like this:

```
public class newViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<level> levels{ get; set;}
   public OldModel oldModel {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Model class

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> EnterpriseList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var model = new TestViewModel() {
            EnterpriseList = EnterpriseData.Select(p=>new SelectListItem() { Value = p.Value,Text = p.Name}).ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.Enterprise, Model.EnterpriseList, "Please select a", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto" })
```

Comment: The model does not contain a property name `Enterprise` so your code would not even compile